# Should I disclose a disability during video interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, disability

I am a grad student actively looking for a job. I never mention my disability (I am a paraplegic using a wheelchair) on resume or during a phone screen to reduce the possibility of prejudice against me as much as I can. The problem is that almost all job interviews are conducted through a videoconference because of COVID-19 and potential employer can’t see me in a wheelchair. Before the coronavirus era it was much simpler - I attended an on-site interview and hiring manager easily figured out that I’m disabled. I didn’t have to explain myself/mention anything.

I am asking because over a month ago I got a verbal job offer from HR after successful video interview, in which I didn’t tell the interviewer about my disability. However, I mentioned it to the person from HR during the call and I got ghosted after that. I didn’t get a formal offer on email with a contract or anything. I sent 2 follow-up emails but got no reply at all. I thought that maybe they considered it a red flag I didn’t tell about it during the interview. On the other hand, it’s an office job and the disability should not affect my productivity at work. The irony is that on the main website of the company they brag about how they care about diversity, inclusion etc. Such an awful experience is really disheartening.

What do you think? Should a disability, which does not affect productivity, be disclosed during the interview, after getting a job offer or not at all?

Comment: brush it off and keep job searching. It's just life. When you have an issue out of your control, you don't let it or peoples reactions impact on your morale. I'm surprised you haven't worked this out already, are you recently disabled?

Comment: I agree.  You're in a wheelchair – so what?  Go ahead and let them see it in the video.  Don't *assume* that people are going to discriminate against you.

Comment: You just have not applied to the right job yet. I have a disabled friend - wheelchair bound and is doing **very** well in an international company. Ignore the losses and the win will happen. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe of the question mentioned above.  In that case the interviewer would be aware of the disability on a video interview, in this case the OP's disability hasn't been visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I would not mention it until you fill out paperwork.  There is no upside for you and it opens you to discrimination.**

Once they hire you they cannot fire you for your disability, but they can make up a reason not to hire you.  It's very difficult to prove you were not hired because of your disability.

Once you get the hiring paperwork the will ask you to declare your disability.  You need to do it here.  This way you can say the employer was informed and failed to make accommodations.

Hopefully, you were ghosted for another reason, but it might have been due to your wheelchair.  If you got phone numbers, or other emails during your interviews, reach out directly to someone besides the HR rep.  Maybe someone else will be in a position to push this through.

Comment: This is what the law says. Reality looks different, though.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer already, but it depends on locale and other factors. There is another angle though.

I'm not physically disabled but I have multiple issues which are out of my control that can lead to discrimination.

I prefer to be upfront and let them have a good look at what they're hiring because in their place I'd prefer no last minute surprises. I want a job, not a bunch of drama or threats of drama being their first impression of me and vice versa. It would just validate whatever issue they have with my appearance.

As a general rule of thumb when you have an issue out of your control, you don't let it or people's reactions impact on your morale. You brush it off as non constructive and move forwards.